# Compilation errors depends on Matrix entries

Tags: matrices

I have a problem while inserting a Matrix. I did it a couple of times and i had no error before. Here is the code:

```
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
[RGA]_{11} & [RGA]_{12} \\ 
[RGA]_{21} & [RGA]_{22}
\end{array} 
\right] 
\text{  becomes  }
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
[RGA]_{11} & 1-[RGA]_{11} \\ 
1-[RGA]_{11} & [RGA]_{11}
\end{array} 
\right]
$$
```

This doesn't compile, getting errors on line 5, while if I write:

```
$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
[RGA]_{11} & [RGA]_{12} \\ 
a [RGA]_{21} & [RGA]_{22}
\end{array} 
\right] 
\text{  becomes  }
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
[RGA]_{11} & 1-[RGA]_{11} \\ 
1-[RGA]_{11} & [RGA]_{11}
\end{array} 
\right]
$
```

As a stupid example, it compiles! 
Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: put a `\relax` before the `[` otherwise it is seen as part of `\\[2pt]`

Comment: if you used `amsmath` `bmatrix` you would not need `\left..\right` or `{cc}` and it would be enough to put the `[` on the next line, as you have it.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, i'm at my first few documents using Latex, so i lack on experience and knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

In line with David's comments....  Also, avoid $$ and RGA should presumably not look like a product of three variables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\rga}{\text{[RGA]}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\rga_{11} & \rga_{12} \\ 
\rga_{21} & \rga_{22}
\end{bmatrix} 
\text{  becomes  }
\begin{bmatrix}
\rga_{11} & 1-\rga_{11} \\ 
1-\rga_{11} & \rga_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```